# Override ActionDispatch::Request method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get my head around the concept of object orientation and inheritance in Rails coming from a procedural background, and particularly I want to understand how I would override default behaviour in classes in the Rails framework.

Say for example I wanted to override a method in ActionDispatch::Request, I assume I do something like this:

```
Request < ActionDispatch::Request

 def method_i_want_to_override
  actions_to_perform
 end

end
```

I am confused though how I load this in order for it to change the way the ActionDispatch::Request object behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you override a method by using inheritance (i.e. you're inside a subclass), you can just declare the method again, like you have done:

```
def method_that_exists_in_superclass
  # stuff here
end
```

Now, *often* you don't want to re-implement the entire method behaviour, you just want to do something additional to what it already does (or undo something it does).  In this case you use `super` to call the original method:

```
def method_that_exists_in_superclass
  result = super
  result + 7 # for example... but use your imagination
end
```

You can also pass arguments to super, as you'd expect, which means you can override arguments by hard-coding one of your own:

```
def method_that_exists_in_superclass(arg1, arg2)
  super(arg1, :foo)
end
```

If you call `super` without any arguments, all of the arguments from the subclass' method are passed along to the parent.  This includes any block that was given.